# EWS: the simplest way to enumerate folders and to determine wellknown folders from them

Tags: exchangewebservices

I use the following code to enumerate folders:

```
FolderView view = new FolderView(100);
view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
view.PropertySet.Add(FolderSchema.DisplayName);
view.PropertySet.Add(FolderSchema.FolderClass);
FindFoldersResults results = service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot, view);
foreach (Folder folder in results.Folders)
{
    if (folder.Id.FolderName != null)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("WellknowFolder is found");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, message box is never shown. For all folders FolderName(in property Id) is null. Even the folder is well-known folder like Contacts, Calendars and so on. Id contains only UniqueId. What is the simplest way to enumerate folders and to determine wellknown folders from them?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the FolderSchema.WellKnownFolderName property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.folderschema.wellknownfoldername(v=exchg.80).aspx in your property set eg

```
view.PropertySet.Add(FolderSchema.WellKnownFolderName);
```

As documented this will only work in Exchange 2013

Cheers
Glen